How to handle PAYMENT.CAPURE.DECLINED Event
after the capture interface is called by the server, the server's webhook interface receives PAYMENT.CAPURE.DECLINED event What should the server do next after the ? Can I directly set my order as failed?
Current operation: Set the external payment order as pending and wait for PayPal's subsequent webhook results

If the capture is declined, PayPal will not retry to capture, so your order is failed unless you retry by calling capture again.
